# LINQ wrapper class around binary DataType

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, generics

I have a LINQ to SQL class called Data with a column of type Data.Linq.Binary.  I want to create a wrapper class that extracts the actual object from the Binary field.  I have multiple classes that store information in the Data table. I know by context, as in each class that stores information in the Data table ALWAYS stores the same type.  I have a class `Something` with a method that adds/reads a `string` to/from the Data table.

```
class Data // LINQ to SQL generated
{
     System.Data.Linq.Binary Value {get; set;}
     string Name {get; set;}
     int ID {get; set;}
}

class Something
{
   void Add(string s)
   {
      //using (db)
      Data.Value = s.ToBinary(); //Convert the string to a byte[] then to Binary
   }
}
```

I then want a property that reads from the Binary column:

```
class Something
{
   string Value
   {
      //using (db)
      get{ return Data.Value.ToString();//Convert to byte[] then to string }
   }
}
```

This by itself works perfectly fine, but I have *multiple* classes that do this same interaction.  Naturally I want an interface or an abstract class, something like this:

```
interface Binary<T>
{
   void Add(T t);
   T Value {get;}
}
```

Here is my problem: In the Value getter I have a linq query that actually returns the LinqToSql Data class with a `Linq.Binary Value`, but in my interface I have a `T Value`.  How do I cast a linq query to this Binary interface?  Something like this, although it doesn't work:

```
List<Binary<T>> Value
{
   get
   {
        return (from D in db.Data
                select D).Cast<Binary<T>>();
   }
}
```

Edit: I had the wrong Property at the very end.  It should be Value, not Name.

Comment: You haven't shown any actual *implementations* of `Binary<T>` - do you have some?

Comment: I'd like Data to somehow implement it, but I don't think LinqToSql classes can be generic.  Perhaps I need to make Binary<T> a class instead of an interface and just have explicit and implicit conversions to and from Data.  I think I'm trying to be too cute with the abstractions.  I probably just want a class that wraps around Data that takes a generic argument.

Comment: @Liz: No, I wouldn't expect you to be able to make the LINQ to SQL classes generic. I'm not even sure I'd use conversions - I think I'd probably just have methods.

Comment: So something like .ToString(), .ToSomeOtherClass(), then the classes can just call the conversion for whatever datatype they need.  Sounds reasonable.

Comment: @Liz: Yes, that sounds appropriate to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want your `Data` class to be generic itself, it has to implement `Binary<T>` for a particular `T`, i.e. `string`, so the class declaration looks like this:

```
class MyDataWrapper : Binary<string> 
{
   ...
```

In that case the Name implementation looks something like this:

```
List<Binary<string>> Name
{
   get
   {
        return (from D in db.Data
                select D).Cast<Binary<string>>();
   }
}
```